# Deactivate F1 Help on Ubuntu 21.10 to use Tilda terminal

Tags: 21.10, shortcut-keys, tilda

I just updated to 21.10. I was used to and loved using [Tilda](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda) with F1 to drop it down and up. This does not seem to work on 21.10 easily. I couldn't deactivate the F1 help function, i.e. whenever I press F1, depending on the active window, the help window appears. Also other Fx keys don't seem to work for tilda (and anyways I really would like to get it to work with F1 again).

Is there a hacky way to deactivate the built-in help on F1 or to make tilda work?

Help is much appreciated!

PS: I'm using a laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is no fundamental solution, because Tilda does not support Wayland.

If you use the default Ubuntu desktop based on Gnome Shell, you could try the Gnome Shell extension [quake-mode](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1411/quake-mode/) by repsac-by. To the developper, this extension was primarily aimed at being able to get Tilix to work under Wayland.

Switching back to Xorg also remains an option: on the log in screen, you can, before entering the password, use the cog wheel to switch to a session on Xorg.

With respect to the F1 key: that is a key that is defined at the level of the application. It will thus be overridden by a global key definition. On Xorg, applications can set these for themselves. On Wayland, applications cannot do that anymore. If Tilda would support a command line interface to toggle its display, you could set a custom shortcut key for that in the Settings. It currently doesn't, however.

Comment: Nice, I like the option to switch to Xorg (is that the same as X11?). Tilda seems to work. Is there a drawback to using Xorg instead of Wayland?

Comment: X11 is the network protocol used by Xorg, so yes, its the same ;) I continue using Xorg because screencasting is better supported, automation of keyboard input is possible with xdotool, and command line tools are available to manipulate open windows.

Comment: I couldn't get Quake Mode working on Ubuntu 21.10 GNOME 40.4.0. I installed it with `gnome-extensions install` but - it doesn't show in `gnome-extensions list` and I can't work with it using `gnome-extensions` commands like prefs (`Extension „quake-mode@repsac-by.github.com“ doesn't exist`). However, it tells me it's already installed when I try installing it again. I tried both versions 4 and 5 for shell 40.

Answer (score 0):

Applications like this try to globally bind keys for their activation.
Wayland doesn't allow this anymore, so you have to go through your desktop environment to manually bind the key.

Terminals like terminix and guake have command line options to activate their pull down ("quake mode"), so you can add a keyboard shortcut in global settings to run that command.  But tilda does not seem to have this, and does not support wayland.